# Problems with declaring a Cheerio variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I want to declare the variable `$` to the `cheerio.load` function inside my object so that I can then access the cheerio functions from any of my functions.

However whenever I do I get the error `this.$ is not a function`

The code I'm using

```js
var spl = {    
    main: function() {
        fs.readFile("index.html", "utf8", function(err, data){
            if(err) throw err;
            this.$ = cheerio.load(data) // Using context.$ resulted in the same problem 
        });
        this.hasTitleTag() // this gives the error this.$ is not a function
    },

    hasTitleTag: function() {
        return this.$('title').length > 0 ? true : false;
    }
};
```

I'm guessing instead of making a variable `$` in my object it's making it for the `main` function only, I've read online to use the `context` keyword but that doesn't seem to do anything either and I'm unable to find another solution

Comment: How you are importing cheerio into your app?

Comment: Also, FYI, readFile is asynchronous. It calls your callback after it's done reading the file. So `this.$ = cheerio.load(data)` is executed after the rest of your code.

Comment: const cheerio =  require('cheerio');

Comment: isn't readFileSync the async version?

Comment: readFileSync is the synchronous version.

Comment: I see, thanks I'll look into that some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readFile` is async, so the function call happens before the file loads. Do this:

```js
var spl = {    
    main: function() {
        let data = fs.readFileSync("index.html", "utf8");
        this.$ = cheerio.load(data)
        this.hasTitleTag() // this gives the error this.$ is not a function
    },

    hasTitleTag: function() {
        return this.$('title').length > 0 ? true : false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to read up on async and sync :)

Comment: @fiji tl;dr: sync = syncronous, it runs one after another // async = a-syncronous = not-syncronous, it runs multiple things at once